# Loaded content can not call parent's function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a document with:

```
<button class="route" data-route-url="/about">About</button>
&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="route" data-route-url="/about">About</a>

<div id="page-content">
</div>

$('.route').click(function() {
    console.log('.route.click()');
    var url = $(this).data('route-url');
    $('#page-content').html('loading...');
    $.get(url, function(data) { $('#page-content').html(data); });
    return false;
});
```

It works perfectly until this point, and loads the about page.

The about page bring another button that also calls "route":

```
<button class="route" data-route-url="/contact">Contact</button>
```

But, when I click on it nothing happens, and I also dont get the console.log message, so seems that the page, that was first loaded inside the div-content can not see the parent function called route, is this working as expected?

How am I supposed to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Event Delegation with <kbd>[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)</kbd> since your button is added dynamically to DOM, The event registered before doesnot apply to the newly added button. SO you need to go with Event delegation, i.e attach the event to the parent container (which exists already) or document element(as i have used in the code) and set up for delegation once an element with the class '.route' is available anytime now or in future.

```
$(document).on('click','.route' ,function() {
    console.log('.route.click()');
    var url = $(this).data('route-url');
    $('#page-content').html('loading...');
    $.get(url, function(data) { $('#page-content').html(data); });
    return false;
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document.

Comment: That's true. (Or at least, it's one solution.) But why?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the very fast and detaled reply.
The click called the function perfectly, but the "data" was not lodaded by the $.get, I just see the 'loading...' and nothing happens, also no error on the console.
Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: @RobsonMartins which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: OK then this should work for you.. Try this and let me know if this works?

Comment: Hello. I'm writing to thank you again and to confirm that this resolved my problem. It was not working before because of another JS conflicts, I created a new document from scratch to validate the solution and it is perfect. Thank you very much!